# How to show data point in Box Plot highcharts

Tags: database, highcharts, visualization, boxplot

I am using Highcharts box plot is there a way to show data points in highcharts as below
[image]

Where data point will give some addition info on the third parameter.

Please point to sample if this exists in highchart

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `boxplot` series should fill your requirements.

Demo: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/box-plot